# Routes in a package for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am having a problem with accessing the `Auth::user()` in a Laravel package routes file.

I am creating a package for Laravel (using 5.8.9). The package has its own routes in a route file which is being added correctly.

I have created an identical route in the main test site and the package.  I am using composer 'path' to symlink the package into the test site which is on Homestead that I'm using on a windows 10 computer.

The route is simple and I'm just checking to see if a user is logged in, which it is.

```php
Route::get('/home', function () {
    dd(Auth::check());
});
```

In the main site routes file the check is returning `true` as expected.  When commented out and allowing the route file in the package to handle it we get a return of `false`.

I noticed it as was getting an error when trying to run middleware on the package and after some investigating found that the package is not registering the user as being logged in.

Any ideas?  Is it a problem because I'm using the path on composer to symlink?

EDIT:  OK I've ruled out the symlink being the problem by creating a private repo and importing it.  So its now in the vendor as a normal imported package but still getting the same issue.

EDIT2: I just tried to pull a user in the package routes file by just doing a simple

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $user = \App\User::find(1);
    dd($user);
});
```

And get `null` does anyone know if its possible to access the user/core laravel models in a package or is it disabled or a problem with the load order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it, if you use routes that require `auth` in your packages then you need to include the `web` middleware.  If you do not include the `web` middleware then you are not loading some of the functionality that the main framework will load, like sessions.

And if you don't have sessions then obviously you wont be able to retrieve logged in users.

So to get it working you would change the code to

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $user = \App\User::find(1);
    dd($user);
})->middleware(['web']);
```